# Maven find the list of available versions for an artifact

Tags: maven

I wonder if there's any hack (for example a REST API) which displays the available versions for a certain maven artifact from the command line.
Say for example, I'n need to find the available versions for:

```
<groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
<artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
```

Currently, I need to check it by opening the browser and checking on the Nexus portal each time....
Thanks

Comment: Which Nexus version are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the maven metadata. Check [this link](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/maven-metadata.xml), and notice that the URL has the `groupId` and `artifactId` formatted in a particular way

Comment: Thanks, I'll build a shell around that